# QTextEdit: typing in HTML/richttext

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTextEdit and want the user to be able to type rich text which will then automatically be (correctly) shown in the widget (so: formatted).

It works fine when setting the text programmatically (using *setText()*), but not when manually typed. See picture below.. "Input" is set using setText, the following line is manually typed. I would like this line to automatically be formatted a

[image]

What's the (easiest) way to do this? The only way I can think about it to manually catch key events and explicitly set the text as HTML.. But I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, you want your line edit to be smart enough to interpret html and format it accordingly when some html is written in it...?

Comment: Though it is not answering your question, but yet I feel if you have so much of formatting requirement you should use QTextEdit instead of QLineEdit

Comment: Correct, it should interpret (the Qt subset of) HTML (which it is capable of doing). Btw, I am using a QTextEdit. Perhaps it looks like a QLineEdit due to the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "the JinX" already said it will not be so intuitive if you try to capture every key event and then try to change the text to render in HTML.
Though you can use some special key sequences, say "shift+return key" to change the text of current line/entire textedit to to html formatted one.
This is just a suggestion.
In this case more than implementation it is also about what a user will expect.
Changing the text of 1 line/entire textedit from plain to HTML would be easy to achieve as well.

Comment: "... use some special key sequences, say "shift+return key" to change the text of current line/entire textedit to html.." That is a great idea.

Comment: Hmm, any idea how to change the pieces of plain text to HTML? textField->setText(textField->toHTML()) doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: can you try this out..?
textField->setHtml ( textField->toPlainText () );

Answer (score 2):

Manual typed html gets escaped, the < will become a < etc .  .

You wouldn't be able to edit it if that would not be the case, for obvious reasons.
You *could* try adding a [render] button or something like that to render the entered text to html. Trying to render on keypress is very dangerous because it makes it terribly inconvenient and counter-intuitive to type something and then have it magically change the output. Also un-finished markup will probably throw a stick in your wheel.

Also pasting from a rich text source (for example a webpage) keeps the formatting.